# Show performance between IIS and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, iis-7

I have a client who upgraded their IIS server and got more memory / CPU. I'd like to show them that their website with 600+- daily visitors can do just as well on a smaller server running linux, APC, minified js, css etc.

I'm not very familiar with IIS, what is the IIS equivalent of top, vmstat, etc, what can I log for 24h on IIS then compare it to a linux machine?

Comment: doesn't IIS run on windows? in which case you would want to monitor it's CPU usage etc through perfmon - see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process  disclaimer: i'm no expert, hence a comment instead of an answer

Comment: also, this might help: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b75e8926-91f8-4a4d-b4e6-3aa63fc40aa4.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @jammypeach yes their current server is Windows/IIS i'd like to show a comparison of usage between their server and linux

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in showing them improvements in response time you would want to compare requests for the same resource given similar or exactly the same request loads in order to show a direct improvement.  You can use the Time-Taken log field which will give you the total time it took for IIS to process the request starting with the 1st byte it receives from the client and ending with the last response send is completed.

For a time period of 24 hours you can take an average of this metric.

Here's an article describing the [**Time-Taken field**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944884).

If you're interested in the performance of the server itself then you'll need to get into monitoring performance counters for cpu, memory, network, etc.

Comment: This will be good then if I can log the time taken to load the home page of the website. Plus the data from Google Insihgts / Pingdom I can then compare the same with the site running on linux.

Comment: @Anagio Yes.  See also the edit I just added.  There's another piece of the equation you'll want to pay attention to.

Comment: Know of any small programs that log CPU/Memory usage? Maybe I can take an hours worth of data and show them what it would cost on a cloud server rather than dedicated